# Passing message between two html pages using javascript

Tags: javascript, message

I have two HTML pages: source.html and dest.html

- In source.html, I create some buttons (start, stop, pause ...)
- In dest.html, I create a simple clock.

Whenever I click on one of these buttons, the source will send a message to dest. After being processed, the result (based on which button was pressed) will be sent back to the source.
I tried iframe, but it did not work for me. Are there any suggestions that do not use the client-server model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 ways to send the message.

1. In source create a form which submits to dest.html, make sure the method is 'GET'
2. On click of the button set the value of the message and submit the form

   // something like
   document.getElementById('message').value = 'HELLO';
   document.getElementById('form').submit();

2a. You dont need to make the form, you can just redirect with hardcoded url on the source.html button click like

```
window.location = 'dest.html?message=somemessage';
```

1. On submit the dest.html file will open, with the message available in the URL of the page

   var url = window.location+"";

   // if there are multiple parameters you will have to loop and store them in array for single you can use

   var message  = url.substr((url.indexOf('=')+1));
       alert(message);

**2nd Method**
Not tried, store them in cookies when button gets clicked on source.html and read the cookies in dest.html

Comment: dont know why I am not being allowed to indent this.

Comment: 1st method -  it will be a one-way process. The both pages will be open sequantally in one window (tab). source.html loads dest.html, dest.html loads source.html. Not two for a time!
Or it would be the same model opener-child, but it's not neccesary to use forms.

Comment: Ok, it's worked, but can I create 2 pages as a "client-model simulation" ? I mean that, these 2 pages existe on the same time, and whenever source.html send a message to dest.html, it will response back to source.html ?

Comment: Bouncing ideas now : In order to make the client-model simulation, use the second method to store the values in Cookies. And write a javascript function (in both the html pages)which runs periodically and reads the values from the cookies.

Comment: Thanks.

ps: I've made a mistake : client-server, not client-model :)

Comment: Try to use cookies. But it's like a trick, not quite good way.
Why you don't want to use "window.open - opener" architecture or frames? Tell us about conditions of origin those two pages? Who will create them and how?

Comment: Of course, I can use other ways, I created a js lib to ease the communication between devices on local network. It's done, and now I go to the testing phase in which I must test my lib (by sending and receiving messages) to obtain a test coverage as much as possible. They want me to create such an application as I described above.

Answer (score 0):

There is **no way** to do that if the windows are independent (without requests to server). If the both windows aren't of any kind of frames. Because of security reasons.

But if you create dest.html window from source.html, you can use created the window's variable (*window.open*) to manage it and *OPENER* object to manage source.html window.

Comment: So you mean that I must integrate dest.html into source.html, and then use window object to manipulate dest.html ?

Comment: Usually there is no need to do any manipulations btw independent windows. So they use or frames, or creating child window on-fly. All these approaches give you native methods.
But if you need to operate btw tabs you really may try the method with cookies. It must work within a common domain.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can.
Try to use the `window.postMessage()` method.
Plus, you will need to create an event listener if you want to post some message back.

Please follow the steps in [this referrence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage)